# Gap between map and frame border

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have created a map into frame. When i fill the frame with picture it fills fully the whole frame but when i insert in the frame the map it leaves a small gap between the border of the frame and map. I tried to change the maps height but it doesnt help. I have two questions:

1. Why do the code behave like that?
2. How to fill the map properly
       the whole frame?

**Picture:**
[image]

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[


    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>
```

map.css

```
#map {width: 100%;height: 98vh;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
```

Comment: Can we at least see the code?

Comment: You might want to show your CSS/HTML code. You might probably set some margin on the top of your map view.

Comment: @ztan updated question by adding css code but in HTML there shouldn't be any problem actually.

Answer (score 0):

I hope by adding   `margin-top:-5px;` or any other negative number that suits you,  will fill that gap at the top. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ikashif/Lsdo68L8/) is the example applied on `div`

Comment: Yes, thank you, it did the trick in top and left but at the bottom and right side there is still this gap, can you help with that?

Comment: You can modify the height property as 'height: 100vh;' if this doesn't solve your problem try 'margin-bottom: 0px'; or what ever number suits you.